# MySQL/PHP - Pagination, sorting

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to paginate user submitted information into a catalog. At first I had something like this:
/?page=3&count=20&sort=date

```
$floor = ($page-1)*$count;
$ceiling = $count;
SELECT * FROM catalog ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT $floor, $ceiling
```

This, as I have read, is bad since it will count all the results, not stopping at the limit (floor+ceiling).

Now, I'm trying to make it faster by paging with respect to the last item on the page

/?last_date=2012&count=20&sort=date

```
$ceiling = $count;
SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE date>$last_date ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT $ceiling
```

However, this won't work right? Some dates will be the same. For the sake of argument, let's assume that I cannot use a more precise timestamp. For instance sorting by price would only go to 2 decimal places and there would definitely be overlap.

Is there anything that I can do to make this improvement work, or should i revert back to my previous query?

Comment: Your first approach looks good to me. Can you be clear why you say its wrong?

Comment: Off topic, but might I suggest making an upgrade to using Jquery for paginating purposes.

Comment: I agree with @GustavoVargas, why have you abandoned your first implementation? And I agree with Norse, you might be rewritting functionality you could implement from frameworks.

Comment: use of the LIMIT keyword in MySQL does not preclude it from reading the preceding records.

For example:

SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10000, 20;

Means that MySQL will still read the first 10000 records and throw them away before producing the 20 we are after.

So, when paginating a large dataset, high page numbers mean long load times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using my first pagination example.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use this, you'd have to constrain by date in both directions. What you could do is multipage each date range if it is too long, otherwise, select the whole set of dates. The disadvantage is that page sizes will be somewhat arbitrary and it might take longer to page through results in some cases.

This would mean you'd also have to first do a count() on that date range so you'd know if the next page would be in this or the next range of dates.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand it good, i think the LIKE operator in WHERE Clause in you SQL Statement should help... But i can be wrong, can you more specify what's exactly wrong?